# Excel not updating pasted as value formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Try these steps: 
 
1. Open excel 
2. Enter 3 value in cell A1 
3. Enter A in cell B1  
4. Enter 1 in cell C1 
5. Enter ="="&B1&C1 in cell B5 
6. Copy cell B5 
7. Select cell B6 and right-click Paste Special then select Values and click OK 
8. Cell B6 shows =A1 formula now.... but why is it not calculating this formula?

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to do this is to paste your formula into required cells then highlight them by selecting the column and then click the "Calculate Now" button:

[image]

This will update the results of the formulae.

If this used to work then it could be that the calculation options have been set to manual. Click on the menu and select "Automatic":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Excel doesn't run the cell through its interpreter after a paste, so your cell value is still a string of text.

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to force Excel the reinterpret the cell.

However, if you using cells B1 and C1 to build a cell reference then you should probably use the `INDIRECT()` function.

Comment: I got that turn around too. Thanks. but that wont help much because i have about a thousand cells that contains the same data.

Comment: I have this problem often enough that I made a macro to do it for me as assigned it to a button on the ribbon. It works for any size selection of cells.    
Private Sub recalcCells(): Selection = Selection.Value: End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I find a solution:
Copy paste the cells into a new workbook.
Saveas the workbook into a tab delimited text file.
Open the text file in notepad
Copy the whole contents
and paste it back into the excel.
Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the "Pasted as Value" Cells
2. Copy (CTRL +C)
3. Paste (CTRL +V) replacing those cells themselves; (Don't "Paste Special")
4. Excel will update those Cells